# WiX - Find parent of .msi directory

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.7

I am using WiX to create a custom installer. I want to navigate one directory up from the .msi's directory in order to find the path of an executable file. After doing some research, I found that [OriginalDatabase] points to the .msi's location, but I don't know how to search **up** from that location instead of down. Here is my search code:

```
<Property Id="SHORTCUT">
    <DirectorySearch Path="..\[OriginalDatabase]" 
                     Depth="0" 
                     AssignToProperty="no" 
                     Id="MainSearch" >

        <FileSearch Name="Program.exe" Id="EXESearch" />
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

WiX will not let me add the "..\" in front of a preset directory path. I don't know how else to navigate up from that folder. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *If* Windows Installer allowed this (which I don't think it does), your path reference would be wrong anyway. The proper one would be `[OriginalDatabase]\..`, which is "the parent of the OriginalDatabase folder".

Comment: I tried [OriginalDatabase]\.. as well and that didn't work.

Comment: I said "(which I don't think it does"). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer has no such ability.  You'd have to write a custom action to resolve OriginalDatabase and then work up to the parent from there.

Comment: I'm pretty new to WiX, any idea what that custom action would look like?

Comment: That depends on what language you program it in.  C# would look something like   session["SHORTCUT"] = new DirectoryInfo(session["OriginalDatabase"]).Parent.FullName;

Comment: Sorry, I'm too new to upvote but I will definitely accept this.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let people know how I solved this, here's my script (I had to write it in vbscript). It's very messy, but it works:

```
Session.Property("SHORTCUT") = Left(Session.Property("OriginalDatabase"), InStrRev(Session.Property("OriginalDatabase"), "\") -1)
Session.Property("SHORTCUT") = Left(Session.Property("SHORTCUT"), InStrRev(Session.Property("SHORTCUT"), "\") -1)
```

Comment: Just in case you haven't read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx